# Entity Framework 6 Migrations class Library project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with an asp.net core mvc project working against the full .net framework and a class library project with all my domain logic, entities, context and all that since I want to have full EF6 with my core mvc project. I created all my entity classes and modeled their relationships and all. I enabled migrations which was successful and added my first migration which also went well. Upon issuing the command update-database, I get this error:

> PM> Update-Database
>       Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>       System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.BinaryPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
>       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context) at    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
>       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>       Sequence contains no matching element

I am not a sure what this message means so can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?!

Comment: what about `update-databse -Verbose`and check what it says?

Comment: To read the error message, `Single(...)` is invoked somewhere even if the data in entity is empty. It would be helpful if you append `DataContext` and `Migration` codes.

Comment: @CodeNotFound -verbose doesn't get to show anything

Comment: @youngjae, will paste dbcontext and migration codes then. But Single() in my code is in projections so a bit confused at d error

Comment: @Eagletrophy // If you have `Single` somewhere, how about to replace `Single` with `FirstOrDefault`? It is safer code.

Comment: @youngjae, will check but i think its singleordefault

Comment: can't add my dbcontext and migration file as character constraint won't allow for that. But does anyone see anything that tell me where I am headed with this error?

Comment: Hi guys, so I tried to run the same domain project in an mvc 5 project, so I just moved my entities, business logic, interfaces and others into the MVC project structure, arranged in folders and I ran the migration commands again and update database was successful with no errors whatsoever! The question now is, do you guys see what is causing these errors, cos I don't!

Comment: Hey guys, I wanted to update my question with this comment, this error happens when I configure my context to use mysql. I am using the latest mysql nugets too. when I use sqlserver localdb, it works fine, migrations apply but when I try to use any linq to access data from the localdb i get errors. will paste the errors. any ideas?